# DNS not resolving after adding CAA record in Route 53

Tags: cname-record, amazon-route53, amazon-acm, caa-record

I have a domain, let's say sameer.com, managed in namecheap.
And a domain, product.com, managed in AWS Route53.

The following DNS records exist for sameer.com:
`CNAME quotes.sameer.com sameer.product.com`
`CAA sameer.com 0 issue "lenscrypt.org"`

And the following records for product.com:
`A *.product.com <AWS_LOADBALANCER>`

Now if I run `dig quotes.sameer.com`,
it resolves to the AWS loadbalancer IP addresses.

So far so good.

Now, if I try to issue a certificate through AWS, for domain `quotes.sameer.com`,
ACM throws a CAA error, because Amazon is not allowed to issue certificate.

Now there are 2 things I can do.

1. Add a CAA record under root domain sameer.com (in namecheap)
2. Add a CAA record under sameer.product.com (in Route53)

Now if I add the CAA record 
`CAA sameer.product.com 0 issue "amazon.com"`,
AWS is able to issue the certificate successfully.

However, once I add this CAA record,
the `dig quotes.sameer.com` command is not resolving.
When I `ping quotes.sameer.com`, it says "Unknown Host".

I don't think CAA record should interfere while resolving a CNAME.
Please help. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how CNAME & CAA records work.

> ##### [RFC 2181, 10.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181.html#section-10.1) CNAME resource records
>
> The DNS `CNAME` ("canonical name") record exists to provide the
> canonical name associated with an alias name.  There may be only one
> such canonical name for any one alias.  That name should generally be
> a name that exists elsewhere in the DNS, though there are some rare
> applications for aliases with the accompanying canonical name
> undefined in the DNS.  An alias name (label of a `CNAME` record) may,
> if DNSSEC is in use, have `SIG`, `NXT`, and `KEY` RRs, but may have no
> other data.

On the other hand, [RFC 6844, 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6844#section-3) defines that...

> Multiple properties MAY be associated with the same
> domain name by publishing multiple CAA RRs at that domain name.

and...

> The following property tags are defined:
>
> - `issue <Issuer Domain Name> [; <name>=<value> ]*`:  The issue property
>   entry authorizes the holder of the domain name  or a party acting under the explicit authority of the holder
>   of that domain name to issue certificates for the domain in which
>   the property is published.

#### Possible solutions:

- Add the `CAA` record at the domain APEX and keep using the `CNAME`:

  ```
  example.org.         CAA    0 issue "lenscrypt.org"
  example.org.         CAA    0 issue "amazon.com"
  quotes.example.org.  CNAME  example-org.example.com.
  ```
- Add the `CAA` record and replace the `CNAME` with an `A` record. You would need to update the `A` record when the `example-org.example.com.` changes.

  ```
  example.org.         CAA    0 issue "lenscrypt.org"
  quotes.example.org.  CAA    0 issue "amazon.com"
  quotes.example.org.  A      192.0.2.1
  ```
- Add the `CAA` record to the domain of the *canonical* (`CNAME`) hostname and keep using the `CNAME`, e.g.,

  ```
  example.org.              CAA    0 issue "lenscrypt.org"
  quotes.example.org.       CNAME  example-org.example.com.
  example-org.example.com.  CAA    0 issue "amazon.com"
  ```

  Here, alias `quotes.example.org` (#2; `CNAME example-org.example.com.`) would be searched for a `CAA` record before `example.org` (#3), because [RFC 6844, 4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6844#section-4) defines the order that way:

  > For example, if a certificate is requested for `X.Y.Z` the issuer
  > will search for the relevant CAA record set in the following order:
  >
  > 1. `X.Y.Z`
  > 2. Alias (`X.Y.Z`)
  > 3. `Y.Z`
  > 4. Alias (`Y.Z`)
  > 5. `Z`
  > 6. Alias (`Z`)
  > 7. Return Empty

  However, parent domain(s) of an alias (here `example.com`) is missing from this order, so you would need to add a distinct `CAA` record for every subdomain.

Comment: Yes true.
But in my case, this is a customer, and the customer doesn't want to add an amazon CAA record for the root domain.

Comment: Then they must add an `A` record and the `CAA` record for the subdomain. That would require updating the `A` record every time the IP address changes, but is the way around the limitations of a `CNAME`.

Comment: hmm... got it..
But since they have a CNAME record pointing to my domain, why can I not add the CAA under my domain?
Since any DNS lookup will follow CNAME records right?

Comment: I guess I can do what you suggested under my domain as well.
Will try and get back

Comment: Sure, that's possible, too. I've updated my answer to cover all three alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed. Thanks to @Esa Jokinen 
`dig quotes.sameer.com` was not resolving after I added the CAA record because
when a specific resource set is found (regardless of it being A record, CAA etc), it will not check the wildcard of the same domain which in my case is `*.product.com`
So 
`CAA sameer.product.com 0 issue "amazon.com"`
hides 
`A *.product.com <AWS_LOADBALANCER>`

So the solution was to add another A record for `sameer.product.com`:
`A sameer.product.com <AWS_LOADBALANCER>`